# Unflatten N-Columns XML to tree structure

Tags: xml, xslt, tree, transformation

I have a problem creating XSLT, that will unflatten that structure:

```
<RS>
    <R>
        <C0>A</C0>
        <C1>B</C1>
        <C2>C</C2>
        <C3>D</C3>
        <C4>1</C4>
    </R>
    <R>
        <C0>A</C0>
        <C1>B</C1>
        <C2>C</C2>
        <C3>E</C3>
        <C4>2</C4>
    </R>
    <R>
        <C0>A</C0>
        <C1>B</C1>
        <C2>F</C2>
        <C3></C3>
        <C4>3</C4>
    </R>
</RS>
```

alternatively that structure:

```
<RS>
    <R>
        <C0>A->B->C->D</C0>
        <C1>1</C1>
    </R>
    <R>
        <C0>A->B->C->E</C0>
        <C1>2</C1>
    </R>
    <R>
        <C0>A->B->F</C0>
        <C1>3</C1>
    </R>
</RS>
```

into this XML nested tree:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>1</D>
            <E>2</E>
        </C>
        <F>3</F>
    </B>
</A>
```

In other words: I want to take 1-N columns (alternatively: first column '->' delimeted string value) as path and convert it into nested XML nodes with last column as node value.

I'm struggling over week now, and started to enjoy the transition from XML to JSON.

Comment: 1. This question is difficult enough without having alternative inputs. Pick one of the alternatives and if the solution does not cover the other one, post a new question. 2. It's not clear what in the example is given and what is just an example - e.g. are the names of the elements `C0`, `C1` ... known in advance? What if the value of one of these is not a valid element name? 3. Which XSLT version does your processor support?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.
Yes, structure will be known in advance, XML input is XML Analysys Rowset (<RS xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">) from reporting tool.
I assume that XSLT 2.0 will be max version on PROD. But my safe guess is that finally will be 1.0 (don't ask why, this client just work that  :)), So all alternatives are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT 3 the (slightly changed) input

```
<RS>
    <R>
        <C0>A</C0>
        <C1>B</C1>
        <C2>C</C2>
        <C3>D</C3>
        <C4>1</C4>
    </R>
    <R>
        <C0>A</C0>
        <C1>B</C1>
        <C2>C</C2>
        <C3>E</C3>
        <C4>2</C4>
    </R>
    <R>
        <C0>A</C0>
        <C1>B</C1>
        <C2>F</C2>
        <C4>3</C4>
    </R>
</RS>
```

can be transformed with recursive grouping as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="rows" as="element(R)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="index" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$rows" group-by="*[$index]">
      <xsl:try>
        <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $index + 1)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:catch>
          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </xsl:catch>
      </xsl:try>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="RS">
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(R, 1)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

into

```
<A>
   <B>
      <C>
         <D>1</D>
         <E>2</E>
      </C>
      <F>3</F>
   </B>
</A>
```

The alternative input structure can also be transformed with recursive grouping in XSLT 3, this time using a map as an intermediary data structure:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="rows" as="map(*)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="index" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$rows" group-by="?columns[$index]">
      <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:sequence select="if (exists(?columns[$index + 1])) then mf:group(current-group(), $index + 1) else ?value"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="RS">
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(R ! map { 'columns' : tokenize(C0, '->'), 'value' : data(C1) }, 1)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That algorithm using a map could be adapted to your first input structure by using

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="rows" as="map(*)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="index" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$rows" group-by="?columns[$index]">
      <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:sequence select="if (exists(?columns[$index + 1])) then mf:group(current-group(), $index + 1) else ?value"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="RS">
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(R ! map { 'columns' : *[. castable as xs:NCName], 'value' : data(*[last()]) }, 1)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```